# Nuget: script for removing a DLL reference in 'uninstall.ps1'

Tags: c#, dll, nuget

Somewhere in the mists of time I found an example of a Nuget *uninstall.ps1* script to remove a DLL reference that I've been blindly copying ever since. This is it:

```
param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package, $project)
$project.Object.References.Remove("Dll.Name");
```

But now when invoking a package uninstall I'm getting an error saying that *Remove* is not a method. What script should I be using to remove a DLL reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not look like [References](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vslangproj.references.aspx) has a Remove method. You can use the following if you know the assembly name.

```
$project.Object.References.Item("System.Xml.Linq").Remove()
```

Comment: It works and is less long-winded than some of the other solutions proposed online.